# Redirect RTMP protocol to another RTMP stream

Tags: flash, stream, ffmpeg, rtmp, rtmps

Is it possible to redirect RTMP protocol to another RTMP stream?

If yes, How can i do it?

In details:
Ex: I got  `rtmp://mydomain.com/stream/redirec`t and i want this to redirect or fetch content/stream from  `rtmp://otherdomain.com/stream/`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using ffmpeg as following
`ffmpeg -i rtmp://otherdomain.com/stream -f flv rtmp://mydomain.com/stream/redirect`

Comment: Hi, I'm getting error for the above command
[rtmps @ 0x33c61e0] Unexpected reply on getStreamLength()
Input/Output Error
Any help? please

Comment: This is a proxy, not a redirection.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it on server side if you are using nginx to handle the request, using the location headers.

"Location:rtmp://otherdomain.com/stream/"

Other method is using proxy pass -

https://github.com/winshining/nginx-http-flv-module

Answer (score 1):

There is another free server for that. You can add endpoint to RTMP streams on Ant Media Server [via rest service](https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server/blob/master/src/main/java/io/antmedia/rest/BroadcastRestService.java#L465). It can even publishes to [social media at the same time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drXSywpuBtQ).

https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Wowza streaming engine](http://Wowza%20Streaming%20Engine) as a `live stream repeater` for that purpose. [This](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?227-Liverepeater-Quick-Start) how-to provides with necessay steps.

Or you can use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) in conjunction with `ffserver` (Linux OS required) to fetch and re-stream your RTMP stream. See [here](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=1193) for more.